# Can I use R Shiny showModal in a loop?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I know there are some similar questions here but they are all a few years old, and all seem to point to using the `shinyalert` package instead of showModal.  My basic problem is that I need to allow the user to select one or more rows in a DT datatable that may have erroneous data, and then gather an input for each row on what the error is so that I can push it back to the database.

Here's a basic example where only the last modal dialog pops up...

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ids <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
firstNames <- c("Bob", "Jane", "Jim", "Billy", "Siouxsie")
lastNames <- c("Smith", "Jones", "Thomas", "Idol", "Sioux")
FaveColors <- c("Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red", "Black")
df <- data.frame(ids, firstNames, lastNames, FaveColors)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Minimal Example"),

    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            tabPanel("Columns",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "ColumnsToShow", label = "Output Columns",
                                         choices = names(df)
                      )
            ),
            actionButton(inputId = "ErrorButton", label="Comment on selected rows")
        ),

        # Show a table
        mainPanel(
          DT::dataTableOutput("FilteredDataFrame")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered_df <- reactive({
    temp_frame <- df %>% select(all_of(input$ColumnsToShow))
    return(temp_frame)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ErrorButton, {
    if (length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected) > 0) {
      for (value in 1:length(input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected)) {
        myString <- paste("You have selected row", input$FilteredDataFrame_rows_selected[value])
        showModal(modalDialog(
          title = "Report possible data error",
          myString,
          easyClose = FALSE,
          fade = TRUE
        ))
      }
    }
    
  }
  )
    

  output$FilteredDataFrame <- DT::renderDT(server=TRUE, {datatable(filtered_df(), extensions = 'Buttons',
                                                                   options = list(scrollx=TRUE,
                                                                                  lengthMenu = c(10,20,30),
                                                                                  paging = TRUE,
                                                                                  searching = TRUE,
                                                                                  fixedColumns = TRUE,
                                                                                  autoWidth = TRUE,
                                                                                  ordering = TRUE,
                                                                                  #dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                                                  dom = 'tlip',
                                                                                  buttons = c('copy', 
                                                                                              'csv',
                                                                                              'excel')
                                                                   )
  )
  }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any way forward with just standard shiny?